# Unable to create a table and import the data from excel using SQL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the below SQL query to create a table and copy the values from an excel:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
DAILY_ALLOWANCE INTEGER
,DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE
,EMAIL VARCHAR(35)
,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(35)
,FULL_NAME VARCHAR(35)
,ID VARCHAR(35)
,NAME VARCHAR(35)
,NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS INTEGER
,OWNERID VARCHAR(35)
,SALARY INTEGER
,TEACHER_UNIQUE_ID VARCHAR(15)
,YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE INTEGER
) copy teacher (
DAILY_ALLOWANCE
,DATE_OF_BIRTH
,EMAIL
,FIRST_NAME
,FULL_NAME
,ID
,NAME
,NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS
,OWNERID
,SALARY
,TEACHER_UNIQUE_ID
,YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE
)
FROM 'C:\Users\Surendra Anand R\Desktop\Note!\Files\Teacher.csv' csv header;
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "copy"
LINE 14: ) copy teacher (
```

Could anyone please explain what I'm missing?.

Comment: You can use `create table` together with `copy`. You need to run `create table` first, then you can `copy` into it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?. Cause this query has been working. But now I'm getting the above error. The entire query is run as a single query where I've tried to create a new table and copy a value from a csv file like you mentioned.

Comment: As I wrote: you need to run **two** commands - one after the other.  First the `create table` after that, you can run the `copy` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @a_horse_with_no_name clarified,

The query needs to be run one by one.